# HTML5 3D car Animation

Tags: html, animation, webgl

I'm trying to do an animation in HTML5 using WEBGL and three.js.
"in this animation a 3d car model comes in from background and stops at point and rotates once."
All the examples i got in internet had controls with mouse or keyboard.
i don't to use want any controls of keyboard or mouse. i want just the animation happening without any keys being used.

```
// JScript source code
// Constructor
ModelViewer = function () {
    Sim.App.call(this);
}

// Subclass Sim.App
ModelViewer.prototype = new Sim.App();

// Our custom initializer
ModelViewer.prototype.init = function (param) {
    // Call superclass init code to set up scene, renderer, default camera
    Sim.App.prototype.init.call(this, param);

    // Create point lights to show off the model
    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 200);
    light.position.set(0, 20, 0);
    this.scene.add(light);

    light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 200);
    light.position.set(-20, 0, 0);
    this.scene.add(light);

    light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 200);
    light.position.set(20, 0, 20);
    this.scene.add(light);

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 200);
    light.position.set(-20, 50, 20);
    this.scene.add(light);

    var amb = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x808080, 1);
    this.scene.add(amb);

    this.camera.position.set(ModelViewer.CAMERA_START_X, ModelViewer.CAMERA_START_Y, ModelViewer.CAMERA_START_Z);

    this.createModel();
    this.createCameraControls();
    //this.updateCamera();
}

//Load texture images here..
ModelViewer.prototype.createModel = function () {
    // Create the model and add it to our sim
    var sb = "../images/SwedishRoyalCastle/";
    var urls = [sb + "px.jpg", sb + "nx.jpg",
                 sb + "py.jpg", sb + "ny.jpg",
                 sb + "pz.jpg", sb + "nz.jpg"];

    var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls);
    //textureCube = null;

    var camaroMaterials = {

        body: new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xC0C0C0, envMap: textureCube,combine: THREE.MixOperation, reflectivity: 0.3 }),
        chrome: new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, envMap: textureCube }),
        darkchrome: new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x444444, envMap: textureCube }),
        glass: new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x223344, envMap: textureCube, opacity: 0.25, combine: THREE.MixOperation, reflectivity: 0.25, transparent: true }),
        tire: new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x050505 }),
        interior: new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x050505, shininess: 50 }),
        black: new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x000000 })

    }

    var materials = [];
    materials.push(camaroMaterials.body); // car body
    materials.push(camaroMaterials.chrome); // wheels chrome
    materials.push(camaroMaterials.chrome); // grille chrome
    materials.push(camaroMaterials.darkchrome); // door lines
    materials.push(camaroMaterials.glass); // windshield
    materials.push(camaroMaterials.interior); // interior
    materials.push(camaroMaterials.tire); // tire
    materials.push(camaroMaterials.black); // tireling
    materials.push(camaroMaterials.black); // behind grille

    var model = new Model();
    // Model from Turbosquid
    // http://www.turbosquid.com/Search/Artists/dskfnwn
    // http://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/411348
    model.init({ url: "../models/Camaro/CamaroNoUv_bin.js", materials: materials });
    this.addObject(model);
}

ModelViewer.prototype.createCameraControls = function () {
    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    var radius = ModelViewer.CAMERA_RADIUS;
    //controls.scale = ModelViewer.CAMERA_SCALE;
    controls.rotateSpeed = ModelViewer.ROTATE_SPEED;
    controls.zoomSpeed = ModelViewer.ZOOM_SPEED;
    controls.panSpeed = ModelViewer.PAN_SPEED;
    controls.dynamicDampingFactor = ModelViewer.DAMPING_FACTOR;
    controls.scaling = ModelViewer.CAMERA_START_Z;
    controls.noZoom = true;
    controls.noPan = true;
    controls.staticMoving = false;


    controls.minDistance = radius * ModelViewer.MIN_DISTANCE_FACTOR;
    controls.maxDistance = radius * ModelViewer.MAX_DISTANCE_FACTOR;
    controls.scaling = ModelViewer.CAMERA_START_Z - ModelViewer.scaler;
    this.controls = controls;
}



ModelViewer.prototype.update = function () {
   this.root.rotation.y += 0.01;

    //this.root.scale -= 0.000000001;
   // this.root.scale.x+=0.000001;
    this.controls.update();

    Sim.App.prototype.update.call(this);
}

//ModelViewer.CAMERA_SCALE = 100;
ModelViewer.CAMERA_START_X = 0;
ModelViewer.CAMERA_START_Y = 5;
ModelViewer.CAMERA_START_Z = 55;
ModelViewer.CAMERA_RADIUS = 22;
ModelViewer.MIN_DISTANCE_FACTOR = 1.1;
ModelViewer.MAX_DISTANCE_FACTOR = 20;
ModelViewer.ROTATE_SPEED =2.0;
ModelViewer.ZOOM_SPEED = 3;
ModelViewer.PAN_SPEED = 0.2;
ModelViewer.DAMPING_FACTOR = 0.3;
ModelViewer.scaler = 1;

//Custom model class
Model = function () {
    Sim.Object.call(this);
}

Model.prototype = new Sim.Object();

Model.prototype.init = function (param) {
    var group = new THREE.Object3D;

    var that = this;

    var url = param.url || "";
    if (!url)
        return;

    this.materials = param.materials;
    var scale = param.scale || 1;

   this.scale = new THREE.Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
   // this.scale = new THREE.Vector3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    var loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
    loader.load(url, function (data) {
        that.handleLoaded(data)
    });

    // Tell the framework about our object
    this.setObject3D(group);
}


Model.prototype.handleLoaded = function (data) {
    if (data instanceof THREE.Geometry) {
        var geometry = data;
        var material = null;
        if (this.materials) {
            material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial();

            var i, len = this.materials.length;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                geometry.materials[i] = this.materials[i];
            }
        }
        else {
            material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial();
        }
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        this.object3D.add(mesh);

        this.object3D.scale.copy(this.scale);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a live example? or jsfiddle?

Comment: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnDAL5alLmw"
Please go through this link. In this video a car comes from a position in the window and rotates once and goes back to its original position.
That is what i'm trying to do. Thank you for your reply Kess Sonnema